# Private tags - Can we enforce NDAs?

Tags: feature-request, tags, visibility

It has been explained (and I agree with this) that [SEI has no *obligation* to enforce NDAs.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94465/should-moderators-enforce-ndas-for-software-vendors) However, enforcing NDAs may *enable* some of our community projects. For example, [Gaming would like to have its users take part in closed betas](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2359/community-promotional-grant-movement-closed-beta-system). Most of those are protected by NDAs, but it would be nice if we could have content on the game online the moment the NDA is no longer effective.

The idea would be "**private tags**", an employee-only option where a tag and its contents are only visible to whitelisted users (those who are under the NDA). They can ask, answer and collaboratively edit their content normally; when the release day comes, a swtich is flipped and the questions become visible and googleable immediately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Secret Meta Stack Overflow](http://so.mrozekma.com/secret-meta.png)

Comment: Intriguing! The legal ramifications are not trivial, though, since Stack Exchange, Inc would likely be required to sign an NDA (sign the data is in their database), and such an NDA might restrict what SEI can do going forward.  But if they can make it work out, it would be a boon for us, especially around WWDC, Google IO, etc.

Comment: Isn't this effectively just asking for built-in fastest-gun-in-the-west support for when a new game comes out?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

NDA's are usually for such a short time span involving only a small proportion of any community (games, developers, network engineers etc). The discussion would most likely be covering bugs and issues that are resolved before RTM and so have no value for the public at large after RTM.

Also the NDA preview stuff I've been involved in only permitted discussion on communication channels that are hosted and controlled by the vendor.

Additionally some NDA's don't permit any discussion of what happened during the NDA or some communications are required to remain confidential even after the NDA is over.

Stack Exchange would also be put under the unnecessary burden of ensuring these discussions remained secret. Stack Exchange employees and moderators would by extension be required to sign these NDA's as well because they have visibility of the discussions.

I think this is a minefield.

Comment: The Gaming one was an example. I'm a mod for Gaming hence the perspective.

Comment: Ok cool, I see what you mean...I took out the first sentence. :)