# Private tags or other private searchable annotations

Tags: feature-request

I would like to have private tags. That is, tags invisible to others but which are searchable for me. Maybe, they could start with some prefix like — `private-` or uid-?

(I looked at the related questions: I am not interested in [private sharable tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94597/private-tags-can-we-enforce-ndas) nor [private notes as such](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76759/private-notes-on-questions) nor [user profile annotations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92008/private-profile-tags).)

Why I need this: It is very difficult to localize existing good answers. For my tags, there are often excellent answers with 2 votes or less ... So questions are very often reanswered. By permitting my own private annotations it would be much easier to locate those answers. The only alternative I can imagine would be to maintain my own external pages referring back to SO. But before I do that, I'd better ask.