# Should we fix postimg.org links to postimg.cc?

Tags: discussion, images, broken-link

For some reason, I can't access https://postimg.org anymore.

For instance, on Stack Overflow, we have [6,605 posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Apostimg.org) with broken images on postimg.org.

But I noticed that the mirror https://postimg.cc is working.

For instance, replacing .org with .cc would fix:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065938/how-to-use-auto-layout-to-move-other-views-when-a-view-is-hidden)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751227/how-to-download-source-in-zip-format-from-github/18583977)
[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30760889/unknown-compiler-version-while-compiling-boost-with-msvc-14-0-vs-2015)
etc. (the vast majority)

- Should we edit all posts one by one to change urls from .org to .cc?
- Should we instead let an admin make an update query to replace them all?

Comment: I'd recommend making a copy of all those images onto the Stack Exchange Imgur account to prevent further link rot in case that mirror goes down as well.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog impossible to copy those, for copyright reasons.

Comment: Actually, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185934/policy-on-uploading-copyright-protected-images-to-imgur