# Edit question offline including in particular pictures, title and text

Tags: discussion, images, uploader

I often prepare a Stack Exchange question when I am offline (for example in a train) with my Emacs and then copy and paste it if I am online again.

Now if I include several pictures I have to upload it manually after pasting the question to the online form. Similar problem with the title and the tags.

Is there any better workflow, so I can prepare the question (for example with Emacs) to 100% including pictures, title and text, preview it (maybe also with math) and then upload it with one click or one command from command line (in Linux)?

Comment: Are the pictures already online or do those have to be uploaded as well? If the latter, it's probably going to be a 2-step process at least. Perhaps a temporary fix with symbolic links, but I suspect there hasn't been made a tool for that yet. Definitely not an official one.

Comment: If the pictures are online and I have the link already, it is trivial, but if the pictures are offline, I want to avoid the additional step to upload it manually as described above.

Comment: Imgur is preferred, see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/326413/282094 and ImageShack banning: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263771/282094