# Are we allowed to embed pirated movies on SE?

Tags: discussion, copyright, piracy

Are we allowed to embed full length copyrighted pirated movies on Stack Exchange? If not, what should someone do if they see this happen? I flagged a post that had one but it was declined.

> [Evil queen uses crane to dip slaves in liquid gold for statues](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/45458/evil-queen-uses-crane-to-dip-slaves-in-liquid-gold-for-statues/45460#45460) answered 7 hours ago by Richard
>
> Piracy/Copyright infringement. Full movie posted. – cde 4 hours ago   ***declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention***

I know SE takes copyright infringement very serious, as the standard policy is to ban someone for tag edits that include Wikipedia text, but are pirated movies exempt?

Comment: @random edited. Not a dupe, as this involves direct embedding of movies, not just a link.

Comment: If YouTube think's it's OK then it must be fine to

Comment: @random so it's okay to embed pirated material on SE as long as it's hosted elsewhere? Got it.

Comment: Putting words in folks' mouths is rude, cde. Have you considered editing the post? Flagging the movie on YouTube? Both? You have, it would appear, full editing rights on Movies & TV...

Comment: @shog9 I will abstain from editing or voting that post for obvious reasons.

Comment: What obvious reasons? Isn't there an embedded movie in the post that should be edited out by anyone with edit privileges, or suggested by those who don't? Or was the flag in error?

Comment: We don't like people copy-pasting text into tag wikis because copy-pastes are rarely ever useful and aren't tailored to our community. We *don't want* that content in our tag wikis. Has nothing to do with the legal aspects - we could just as easily edit in the source of the content and attribute appropriately. But that's not what we want here. Your objection here is solely based on the illegality of the video, which is not something we can act upon. All we're even hosting regarding it is a *link*, the actual video isn't even hosted on our network.

Comment: @animuson you sure is not the copy right issue? You may want to let this Stack know what then http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/752/use-of-copied-content

Answer (score 10):

Moderators can not handle legal requests.

Any copyrighted content that you want off the site needs to be done through a DMCA request. You can use the [Contact Us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) page for such a request. You have to be the copyright holder, and prove it, along with some other requirements for such  a request as well.

---

To address the other part of your question, we can remove plagiarism when the community deems it that, and does not want it. The reason why your flag was declined is because your flag was *legal* in nature, and we don't have the tools/experience to handle that. You should be explaining why the content is objectionable, and why it should not be there instead. You can see [What should I do when I see copyright violations posted on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114919/what-should-i-do-when-i-see-copyright-violations-posted-on-stack-overflow?rq=1) for more information.

Comment: So why do they ban people for wiki tag edits or enforce Wikipedia copyrights?

Comment: Explaining why a full length copyrighted movie being embedded is objectionable? You mean other than the whole illegal aspect?

Comment: @cde I've updated my answer. Also, read the answer by casperOne in the dupe that random signalled.

Comment: @cde Illegal in your eyes. You may as well ask yourself why YouTube doesn't take the video down either... After all, they host the video. Stack Exchange is not compelled to take down any content, unless a DMCA Takedown notice has been issued.

Comment: Also, that link says `What to do if you see a problem 
In practice, SE Corporate and the community reserve the right to remove material at any time and for any reason (See http://stackexchange.com/legal, section 3). So if you see something hinky happening, flag it.`

Comment: @cde Did you bother reading the rest of that? **Use the word "copyright" in your flag if you wish, or don't use it; just understand that mods don't have the ability or authority to respond to claims of copyright infringement; they can only respond to "bad things happening." In turn, you don't have the authority to act on behalf of the copyright holder, but you do have the right and obligation to let us know that there are "bad things happening."**

Comment: So embedding full length movies isn't "a bad things are happening" type thing?