# How to deal with a copyright claim?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, copyright

I just encountered this review and I'm unsure what to do with it. Somebody claimed the posted code to be copyrighted.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3533256

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414903/add-a-dynamic-value-as-a-price-on-add-to-cart-wordpress

So should this edit be accepted just on the basis of this claim?  Should it be flagged for moderation?

Comment: Note: that user's other question contains some of the same code.

Comment: Short answer: decline, and if you think there's a point flag the post as "other" and explain, community manager can then see it and handle the case.

Comment: Related: [Why was this question deleted over code allegedly copyrighted by Embarcadero?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114019/182513)

Comment: Well, the user that suggested the edit happens to have [**all his answers**](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2978085/px0r?tab=answers) promoting that very CodeCanyon plugin (for which he claims copyright)... I've flagged one of them for moderator attention.

Comment: @brasofilo not to mention he is engaging in self promotion for a paid product.  I've [commented](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17775972/bounding-box-volume-of-an-stl-file/19900015#comment30560053_19900015) on one of his answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dealing with copyright is not something the community or the moderators can and should do. All claims of copyright violations must be submitted to SE and they'll deal with them. So this edit should be rejected.

But there is a very closely related issue, while we don't deal with copyright, the community still frowns on plagiarism. So if the post in this case is actually copied from another source, it should either be put in a quote and attributed properly if it is a reasonable excerpt and not the whole post is plagiarized, or it should be outright deleted if it is a full copy from another source.

In this specific case, it might be the best to just close the whole question, it does seem too much of a code dump to me.