# Answers suggesting a violation of TOS

Tags: discussion

On the [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook) tag, I have been seeing some users answering questions by suggesting that the OP violate the Facebook TOS.

I will always downvote answers **or** questions that deal with violating Facebook's TOS.  Since Facebook started directing all technical QA about using their platform to the [facebook.stackoverflow.com](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com) filter,  should these posts be flagged and ultimately deleted?

I definitely feel that they should and I'd also like to hear what others think about suggesting this sort of behavior.

Comment: Down-voting and/or commenting is the correct behaviour in these cases.

Comment: Agreed with ChrisF.  It's not our job to enforce Facebook's TOS, so these are still real and valid answers/questions from our perspective.  Doing something like that is a bad idea though, hence downvotes are fine.

Comment: Non-legal activities can generally be commented on or flagged. Facebook isn't a special case there just because SO is in business with it or because of Stockholm syndrome.

Comment: @mario - Moderators aren't here to deal with this sort of thing. Down-votes and/or comments should be enough.

Comment: @ChrisF, I think moderators babysitting external legalese is indeed pointless. But some activites (poster blatantly inquiring about spamming techniques) aren't covered with community voting alone, and flags for quick deletion can be in order.

Comment: @mario: Who says violating Facebook's TOS is "not legal"?

Comment: Here is my answered that prompted this (note i warned the user) http://stackoverflow.com/a/9025926/265570

Comment: @OffBySome, Your question is not directly what prompted this; It was however the first time I've seen a 10k suggest this. (but yea it happened right after I saw your post).  I didn't put links to examples of these sorts of posts (questions and answers) pretty much because of my views on the subject - me posting links to these "offending" posts would defeat the purpose of not wanting this information to be there at all.  I agree that moderators are not here to enforce 3rd party TOS.

Comment: I do **not** agree however that these should be considered "valid" answers.  We're not in the wild-wild-west here :P I do think that some self restraint should be brought into play though.  Its a touchy subject and it **all** depends on the context - but as we all know the majority of questions asked on that filter originate from a lack of understanding of the limitations of the platform; "Just because you want this information - doesn't mean you should *do anything* to get at it"... In this case we **are** dealing with peoples privacy after all...

Comment: @Lix I agree with you there, but I don't see why content like that should be *deleted*. Say somebody asks "how can I get a user's <insert sensitive data point here>", the answer is "it's not possible - it's a violation of privacy, and FB's TOS.". That's a good thing to have on file on Stack Overflow for the next guy who wants to know the same thing, isn't it? Now if somebody provides a way to *circumvent* such a restriction, *that*'s a different matter. But you'll find that such content is already getting deleted on SO on a daily basis. Mod-flagging the contribution should usually do.

Comment: Yea - that's exactly what I'm saying - content that explains how its done - sometimes its in an answer, but I've seen it in a question stating : "Here is my chrome extension that does XYZ *(violation of TOS)*, I'm having problems with the ABC feature *(not relevant because they already posted code showing how the violation is acomplished)*".  Question answer pairs explaining that this is not possible, here is a possible alternative, etc.. are great.

Comment: [A related question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94465/should-moderators-enforce-ndas-for-software-vendors).  Personally, violating facebook's TOS makes me glow with tickles.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> I will always downvote answers or questions that deal with violating Facebooks TOS.

You have the right to vote as you please; your policy is perfectly valid. I personally, however, would look at which part of the TOS is being violated. If it's about circumventing some ridiculous, borderline illegal provision that common sense dictates should be scrapped immediately, I can see myself even upvoting.

> Since facebook started directing all technical QA about using their platform to the facebook.stackoverflow.com filter, should these posts be flagged and ultimately deleted.

I don't think anything should be deleted because it violates a contract that SO is not party to; we are not here to enforce Facebook's (or any other company's) interests. Stuff should be deleted because it's *bad content*. SO's *own* rules are perfectly sufficient for making this decision.

In most cases, questions or answers discussing TOS violations will probably *also* be delete-worthy under SO's rules. But there's no reason to cast this into stone.

Comment: `ridiculous, borderline illegal provision` ftw

Comment: Just *borderline*?

Comment: "look at which part of the TOS is being violated" - definitely true.  I've studied those policies very thoroughly after action was taken against me for some pathetic like button some client requested.  But I was one of the administrators - so I got taken down too.  In my case there aren't any "ridiculous, borderline", etc.. cases - its all to do with privacy - and IMO its all valid.

Comment: @Lix I don't know enough about the Facebook TOS to agree or disagree, but even if what you say is true *now*, who's to say it'll stay that way? What if they add a paragraph to the TOS saying that criticism of Facebook in posts is prohibited? (A dumb example, I know. But you know what I mean.) 
My point is, let's not make a company's TOS the guideline for our actions - let's stick with our own rules, and the law. As said, in most cases, TOS violations will also be violations of SO's rules anyway.