# Which flag should we use for questions which request how to crack?

Tags: feature-request, flags, declined-flags

Update: 
As suggested by Catija in comments, each site has different flagging policy, so I've posted on Stack Overflow meta.
[Stack Overflow meta - Which flag should we use for questions which request how to crack?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360805/which-flag-shuold-we-use-for-questions-which-request-how-to-crack)

Update 2: 
Current conclusion:

> We are never going to get involved with judging whether a question is dealing with an illegal activity.

I'll leave this question for information.

---

Currently we have these type of flags.

- Spam
- Rude or abusive
- Should be closed...
- Duplicate...
- Very low quality
- In need of moderator intervention

But it seems we don't have standard flags for cracks, exploits, or malicious requests. I think it's a reason why we sometimes choose moderator intervention flag and get declined with comments like this:

> declined - Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags: see [What is Flagging?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)

I think "should be closed..." flag is nearest, but its sub menus are:

- Duplicate of...
- Off-topic because...
- Unclear what you're asking
- Too broad
- Primarily opinion-based

And they seem not intended for illegal or shady practices.

So, I want to ask which "standard" flag should we choose for such questions. If no suitable flag exists, please add such a standard flag.

---

Related questions in meta:

- *[Policy regarding questions related to unethical or “shady” practice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80495/policy-regarding-questions-related-to-unethical-or-shady-practices)*
- *[Should I have flagged a question for moderator attention if it covered a “dodgy” topic?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190144/should-i-have-flagged-a-question-for-moderator-attention-if-it-covered-a-dodgy?noredirect=1&lq=1)*
- *[Asking a question that suggests cracking or altering an app without source?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143999/asking-a-question-that-suggests-cracking-or-altering-an-app-without-source)*

Comment: If the Stack Overflow mods declined this flag, you should ask on Meta Stack Overflow. Different sites have different flagging policies, so search MSO for guidance and ask if you can't find anything.

Comment: @Catija Thank you for your information. I've posted on MSO.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360805/which-flag-shuold-we-use-for-questions-which-request-how-to-crack

Comment: [Related on Android.Meta.SE](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2321/205764)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all else fails, a custom flag might work - just make sure its clear what the issue is, since many sites do end up going to massive numbers of flags. Least as a SU mod - this actually feels like a valid reason to custom flag.

That said, I often find questions like that have multiple *other* issues attracting flags or closevotes, these questions are often *also* too broad or unclear. If the outcome but not the method is important, you can always find some other reason to close, and comment about the shadiness of the question as well