# Can or should we delete an answer that violates online course honor code?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, ethics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should moderators enforce NDAs for software vendors?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94465/should-moderators-enforce-ndas-for-software-vendors)

Due to the rise of online courses such as Coursera, the number of questions paired with these courses is on the rise as well. Some of them violate the honor code of said courses (usually, they contain source code or significant spoilers to the homework submission), but they don't violate SO rules directly (or do they?).

What is the etiquette for such questions? [Should we delete them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149906/coursera-says-i-have-violated-the-honor-code), or should we keep them alive?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not in the business of policing the code of honour / NDA / contract of any 3rd party.

Comment: See [Should moderators enforce NDAs for software vendors?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94465)

Comment: @Martijn well it isn't now. Not anymore. But the way we've been treating homework questions for four years on end did [make one wonder](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated#comment422030_147100).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the OP wishes to delete them because they have violated some agreement / honour code, etc. then they can flag the post for moderator attention, with a request to delete them.

However, just like external NDAs, agreements, or contracts, Stack Overflow is not bound by any such regulations, and as a third party, we should treat such questions the same way we treat all other questions.

Also see [Should moderators enforce NDAs for software vendors?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94465/should-moderators-enforce-ndas-for-software-vendors)