# Giving up on an issued flag

Tags: feature-request, flags

I just flagged a few posts that fell under the same reason (NDA related) only to learn from the first flag being declined that SO doesn't enforce NDAs, which I now understand and agree with after reading [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94465/should-moderators-enforce-ndas-for-software-vendors):

My question then is: Shouldn't there be a way for an user to cancel an issued flag that has not been reviewed yet?

Comment: It's been proposed a number of times; it simply doesn't happen often enough to justify adding the feature.

Comment: Just accept the punishment that will follow...mwah...mwahaha...MUWAHAHAHA

Comment: @Servy yup, [currently 13 times](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/87500?lq=1).

Comment: Just FYI: We don't generally try to punish users for this. If I notice a group of the same flag posted at the same time, I'll usually only decline one so I can send a message to the flagger.  If the same user keeps flagging for the same bad reason over time though, those will probably all be declined until they get the message.

Comment: @Bill Out of curiosity, what happens to the other non-declined flags? Do they remain in limbo, disappear or something else?

Comment: @BilltheLizard I see, thanks. Interestingly enough, all the other flags were actually marked as helpful. But the questions were all very low quality, so probably they will eventually be closed for other reasons.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins I usually just mark them as helpful. The user was making a good faith effort to flag something they thought was wrong, so I don't want to completely ban them from flagging by declining 12 flags at once.  If they're persistent over time (likely because they're not checking flag feedback), eventually I'll send them a direct message to stop.

Comment: @Cezar Yeah, I caught a couple that were just low quality and closed them. You should be able to reflag any that should be closed for other reasons now.