# Unsure if question regarding javascript to be used on another site is appropriate

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I'm not sure if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19435638/im-trying-to-find-a-section-of-js-code-that-will-open-every-link-with-the-text), regarding writing your own custom javascript to essentially add a new feature to a web site that you don't administer, is appropriate for Stack Overflow.  It *is* regarding a specific programming problem, so in that regards, it's on topic.  However, it's sort of a "how do I hack this web site" kind of question (which would definitively be inappropriate), though without any malevolent intent.  Should it be closed?

Comment: That question has already been removed.

Comment: [I don't think that it is off-topic.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19495#19495)

Comment: Interesting - the OP must have taken his/her question down almost immediately after I posted this.  And good point Johannes - I didn't think about how the OP's situation isn't that different from someone working on a Grease Monkey script.

Comment: @JoshC it was deleted by the owner.  Discussing if it's on topic is still an appropriate meta question.

Comment: The question is (was) off-topic, because all it said was "fix this code for me".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it should not, for essentially the exact same reasons that [we shouldn't enforce Non Disclosure Agreements on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94465/should-moderators-enforce-ndas-for-software-vendors).  It's not our responsibility to enforce the terms and conditions of the use of scripts on some other site.  If we *do* start moderating that then in fact we can open ourselves up for liability for making the claim that the content on this site doesn't violate the T&C of other sites.