# A duplicate solved the previous thread - how to handle?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it OK to close a question as an exact duplicate of a question that was asked later?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141839/is-it-ok-to-close-a-question-as-an-exact-duplicate-of-a-question-that-was-asked)

So. [A question was raised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11951616/deploy-nodejs-to-heroku), which was pretty much a duplicate of [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674550/socket-io-node-js-on-heroku). Only this time around, in the duplicate, the issue was resolved. Should the earlier one now marked as duplicate? Or the new one? Or the answer added to the old one?