# Order of duplicated questions

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, duplicate-answers

My question: [JARs from library project are not visible in application projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16587326/jars-from-library-project-are-not-visible-in-application-projects) has been marked as duplicate but referenced question was added **later** than mine one. Moreover all answers and comments were added also before the second question was created.
So why question which was added first has been marked as duplicate? Shouldn't order of the question be checked automatically when someone is trying to mark as a duplicate?

If mentioned behavior is intended (eg. later question has better answers) then explanation text in frame is incorrect: *This question has been **asked before** and already has an answer* because other question has been asked **after**.

Comment: duplicate of: [Closing an earlier post as a duplicate of a later one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1375/closing-an-earlier-post-as-a-duplicate-of-a-later-one) and of: [Is it OK to close a question as an exact duplicate of a question that was asked later?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141839/is-it-ok-to-close-a-question-as-an-exact-duplicate-of-a-question-that-was-asked)